# amenable ultrafilters

Tags: logic, set-theory, large-cardinals

Suppose $M$ is a transitive model of ZFC-powerset.  If $\kappa \in M$ is a cardinal and $U$ is an ultrafilter on the boolean algebra $\mathcal P(\kappa)^M$, we say $U$ is *amenable to $M$* if whenever $\{ X_\alpha : \alpha < \kappa \} \subseteq \mathcal P(\kappa)$ is in $M$, then $\{ \alpha : X_\alpha \in U \} \in M$.  In these [notes](http://www.math.cmu.edu/users/jcumming/Appalachian/steel_cmu_2015_files/Iteration-Ultrapowers.pdf), Steel says that if $j : M \to N$ is elementary with critical point $\kappa$, and $U$ is the ultrafilter on $\mathcal P(\kappa)^M$ derived from $j$, then $U$ is amenable to $M$ if and only if $\mathcal P(\kappa)^M = \mathcal P(\kappa)^N$.  I am able to show that $U$ is amenable to $M$ iff $\mathcal P(\kappa)^M = \mathcal P(\kappa)^{Ult(M,U)}$, but I don't see why necessarily $\mathcal P(\kappa)^{Ult(M,U)} = P(\kappa)^N$.  Is the claim true, and how do you show it?

Comment: Factor $j$ into an ultrapower and a second embedding, and show the second embedding has a critical point above $\kappa$ itself.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I need to show the factor map critical point is above $2^\kappa$. Why is that?

Answer (score 4):

The claim is false.

Assume there is a measurable $\kappa$ and for every inaccessible $\delta < \kappa$, there is a precipitous ideal on $\delta^+$.  A model of this can be obtained by forcing from a model with a supercompact and a measurable above it.

Let $i : V \to M$ be the ultrapower embedding by a normal measure $U$ on $\kappa$.  In $M$, there is a precipitous ideal $I$ on $\kappa^+$.  Let $k : M \to N$ be a generic embedding coming from $I$.  Note that $crit(k) = \kappa^+$.  Let $j = k \circ i$.

$U$ is amenable to $V$, and for every $A \in \mathcal P(\kappa)^V$, $\kappa \in i(A)$ iff $\kappa \in j(A)$.  So $U$ is also the ultrafilter derived from $j$.  But $\mathcal P(\kappa)^M \not= \mathcal P(\kappa)^N$, since forcing with $I$ collapses $\kappa^+$.

Comment: Very nice! I can finally move on with my day...

Comment: Do you really need a supercompact? Wouldn't a measurable with $o(\kappa)=1$ (or $2$ if $1$ means just measurable for your count) be enough? Just iterate with Easton support Levy collapses of a large set of measurable cardinals to be successor of inaccessible cardinals and then you get the ideals to exist by the usual chain condition argument?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I want to preserve measurability so the obvious thing to do is collapse the first measurable above kappa in the last step. It’s probably overkill.

Comment: Maybe Woodin is enough using “surgery”?